# Hive Dynamic Partitioning, correct partitions are not created

Tags: hadoop, dynamic, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I'm trying to insert data in to a partitioned table, but not all the partitions were created (only null and zero values are created), please see below.

hive>

```
select state_code,district_code,count(*) from marital_status group by state_code,district_code;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
```

MapReduce Jobs Launched:

```
...
Job 0: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 3.49 sec   HDFS Read: 193305 HDFS Write: 240 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 3 seconds 490 msec
OK
28  000 60
28  532 60
28  533 60
28  534 60
28  535 60
28  536 60
28  537 60
28  538 60
28  539 60
28  540 60
28  541 60
28  542 60
28  543 60
28  544 60
28  545 60
28  546 60
28  547 60
28  548 60
28  549 60
28  550 60
28  551 60
28  552 60
28  553 60
28  554 60
Time taken: 39.442 seconds, Fetched: 24 row(s)
```

I'm now inserting this table data to another table partitioned on district_code.

hive>

```
insert overwrite table marital_status_part partition(DISTRICT_CODE) SELECT * FROM MARITAL_STATUS WHERE DISTRICT_CODE IN ('532','533','534');
Total MapReduce jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
```

Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator

```
Starting Job = job_201507071409_0020, Tracking URL = http://localhost:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201507071409_0020
Kill Command = /home/chaitanya/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201507071409_0020
```

Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers:

```
0
2015-07-07 16:35:38,180 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2015-07-07 16:35:48,214 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.01 sec
2015-07-07 16:35:49,217 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.01 sec
2015-07-07 16:35:50,220 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.01 sec
2015-07-07 16:35:51,222 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.01 sec
2015-07-07 16:35:52,226 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.01 sec
2015-07-07 16:35:53,234 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.01 sec
2015-07-07 16:35:54,237 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 2.01 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 2 seconds 10 msec
Ended Job = job_201507071409_0020
Stage-4 is selected by condition resolver.
Stage-3 is filtered out by condition resolver.
Stage-5 is filtered out by condition resolver.
Moving data to: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive-chaitanya/hive_2015-07-07_16-35-29_099_2560746659196071718-1/-ext-10000
Loading data to table default.marital_status_part partition (district_code=null)
    Loading partition {district_code=0}
Partition default.marital_status_part{district_code=0} stats: [num_files: 1, num_rows: 0, total_size: 22882, raw_data_size: 0]
Table default.marital_status_part stats: [num_partitions: 1, num_files: 1, num_rows: 0, total_size: 22882, raw_data_size: 0]
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.01 sec   HDFS Read: 193305 HDFS Write: 22882 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 seconds 10 msec
OK
Time taken: 26.254 seconds
```

what actually should happen is three folders has to be created with 532, 533, 534, but only 2 folders are created (NULL & zero). Can you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Hive Partitions can be thought of as a 'virtual' column.  On HDFS, they are separated into different directories.  The partition value is taken from the last entry of your select.  Without knowing more about your table columns, the following query should work if with slight modifications.

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE marital_status_part partition(DISTRICT_CODE) SELECT column1, column2, ..., columnN, DISTRICT_CODE FROM MARITAL_STATUS WHERE DISTRICT_CODE IN ('532','533','534');`

In this insert, notice that DISTRICT_CODE is the last column in the SELECT portion.  This last column will be used as DISTRICT_CODE in `partition(DISTRICT_CODE)`.  You need to make sure that the number of columns you are selecting match the number of columns in your target table and include something to partition off of.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-Dynamic-PartitionInsert for details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you executed the below commands?

Set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;

Set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

This is because bydefault Static partitioning is enabled, which may create such issue which you are facing.

(Not able to format above text as I am answering this using mobile phone)